# HorizontalScrollView - Adding Item at specific position

Tags: android, textview, position, horizontalscrollview

I want that the **user** can scroll throw my `HorizontalScrollView` and if he press my `Button`, a `TextView` will be shown on the **current position** of my `HorizontalScrollView`.

So far I already know how to present a `TextView`, but not on a specific position...

```
TextView textView;
textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

Any help is welcomed!
[image]

Comment: current position means?

Comment: The position, which is displayed!

Comment: Do you have screen shot?

Comment: There is my screenshot!

Comment: You can use a Relative layout inside HorizontalScrollview and you can set scrollX() and scrollY() of HorizontalScrollview to the child views margin.

Comment: can you explain this in an answer a little bit more exactly ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some thing like this ,

```
final HorizontalScrollView scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);
        final RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

        findViewById(R.id.addButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                TextView iv = new TextView(Act2.this);
                iv.setText(new Date().toString());

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 400);
                params.leftMargin = scrollView.getScrollX();
                params.topMargin = scrollView.getScrollY();
                container.addView(iv, params);


            }
        });
```

And the relative layout should be inside the HorizontalScrollView. This will add a textview exactly in the current position , but you should also write code for avoiding the overlapping the TextViews.